# Making Bitmap aspect ratio to centerFit Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing, aspect-ratio

I have searched alot for this but got no proper solution!
i have a drawing area in my android app and i want to take image from camera/gallery and set it as a background of canvas.
I get Bitmap after taking photo from camera/gallery and i pass my bitmap to this method to make it aspect fit to my drawView keeping its aspect ratio.
Here newHeight/newWidth are my drawView's height and width.

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
    int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

    // Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
    // To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger 
    // of these two.
    float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
    float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
    float scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);

    // Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
    float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
    float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

    // Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
    // should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
    float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
    float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

    // The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
    // be
    RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);


    // Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
    // scaled bitmap onto it.
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

    return dest;
}
```

It works good on mt Htc m7 but on my galaxy tab4 it makes image strech so sleek as you can see in image below:
[image]

do anyone know any method through which i can set bitmap to my drawView like this

```
Bitmap backgroundBitMap= c.scaleCenterCrop(bmp, drawView.getHeight(), drawView.getWidth());



 String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, MainActivity.this);
  backgroundBitMap=  c.rotateImage(backgroundBitMap,tempPath);

 drawView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(backgroundBitMap));
```

but keeping its aspect ration same. Actually i want CenterFit functionality for a bitmap.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: its to complex,  use Canvas.drawBitmap with a Matrix parameter set with setRectToRect method

Comment: @pskink thanks for your answer. I have tried that too but i doesnt work. Can you provide a working code snippet?

Comment: yes it works pretty nice. i used it several times,  just create proper Matrix and use it

Comment: @pskink Matrix only have option of CENTER which makes bitmap to center crop. But i want functionality of Center Fit where bitmap maintain its aspect ratio and scale down/up according to fit in View. Do you know any method to achieve this?

Comment: CENTER fills (scaling up/down) the image preserving aspect ratio,  it doesn't crop the image

Comment: @psKink yes it surely do. but just have a look on the picture that i have attached. i want image to set like this. Matrix's CENTER fills the whole View area.

Comment: so it seems i don't know what you want...